# Objectify can't find entity that appears to exist

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Objectify 5.1.1 on Google App Engine.  I have defined an Objectify entity called Insight and tried to query it by a boolean property called downloaded.  However, Objectify can't find this entity.

Here's how I'm trying to do the query:

```
Query<Insight> insightQueryTemplate = ofy().load().type(Insight.class).
                filter("downloaded", false).first().safe();
```

Here's a stripped down class definition for Insight:

```
@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity
public class Insight {
    @com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id 
    public Long id;

    public boolean downloaded = false;

    public Insight () { }

}
```

When I look in the development server's datastore I can see the entity does exist but the `downloaded` property says "false (unindexed)" instead of simply "false".

I'm pretty sure this used to work with Objectify 3.1 so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tag `@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index` needs to be annotated on the class like this:

```
@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity
public class Insight {
    @com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id 
    public Long id;

    @com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index  // *** This was missing ***
    public boolean downloaded = false;

    public Insight () { }

}
```

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Unindexed_properties, properties are either set with `setProperty()` or `setUnindexedProperty()`.  But the current [documentation for Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/AnnotationReference#@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index) says that properties are set as unindexed by default.

So I annotated my class with `@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index` and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Indeed, you can only use queries with indexed properties. However, you don't need to index everything (=putting `@Index` on class level), you can and probably should do it per property.  https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries explains all your options.